# Matrix mappings and the implicit function theorem

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, group-theory

Let $A$ be a fixed $k \times k$ invertible, skew-symmetric matrix. Consider a mapping from real square matrices to real skew-symmetric matrices defined by $M \mapsto M^TAM-A$ for some $M\in M_{k}(\mathbb{R})$. I want to show that this mapping satisfies the implicit function theorem around the identity. (Clearly, $I_k\mapsto 0$.)

My problem is that I only know the implicit function with regards to Euclidean spaces, and I'm unsure how to represent $M_{k}(\mathbb{R})$ as $\mathbb{R}^{k^2}$. I looked at the $k=2$ case for some intuition, with $A= \begin{pmatrix}0 & \lambda \\ -\lambda & 0\end{pmatrix}$ for some non-zero $\lambda$. Then for some $M= \begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}$, our mapping sends it to $\begin{pmatrix}0 &\lambda ad - \lambda bc - \lambda \\ \lambda bc - \lambda ad + \lambda & 0\end{pmatrix}$. So say we represented $\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}$ as the column vector $\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{pmatrix}$, then we can view this as a mapping from $\mathbb{R}^4\to \mathbb{R}$ which sends $\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{pmatrix}\mapsto \lambda ad-\lambda bc-\lambda$. The derivative matrix would be $\begin{pmatrix} \lambda d & -\lambda c & -\lambda b & \lambda a\end{pmatrix}$. Then at the identity, this is $\begin{pmatrix} \lambda & 0 & 0 & \lambda\end{pmatrix}$. So since $\begin{pmatrix}\lambda\end{pmatrix}$ forms an invertible $1\times 1$ matrix, our mapping does satisfy the implicit function theorem.

However, it jumps out to me that if we had instead represented $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}$ as $\begin{pmatrix} b \\ a \\ c\\ d\end{pmatrix}$, the first entry of the derivative matrix is now $0$, and our mapping fails to satisfy the conditions of the implicit function theorem. But I've been told this result should hold regardless of the basis used, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

To be honest, I feel like I'm missing the main point of the problem and I'm going in the wrong direction. Any hints?

Comment: The [implicit function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem) supposes to have a map $f : (x,y) \mapsto f(x,y)$. What is $f$ here? What are its domain and codomain?

Comment: What I'm thinking is $M_k(\mathbb{R})$ has dimension $k^2$, while the subspace of skew-symmetric matrices has dimension $k(k-1)/2$. So while the function is not evident, we will end up with $k(k-1)/2$ questions in $k^2$ variables. We can reach explicit functions by calculating $M^TAM$, but I'm not sure if that's the best way to go about the problem.

Comment: Sorry, but I don’t see how we can apply implicit function theorem if you don’t clarify what the function is.

Comment: My question is less-so how to apply the implicit function theorem, but more-so wondering how to represent this mapping of matrices as a function in Euclidean space. The mapping we have right now sends a square matrix $M$ to $M^TAM-A$. I'm pretty sure the domain would need to be $\mathbb{R}^{k^2}$ and the codomain should be $\mathbb{R}^{k(k-1)/2}$. But the $2\times 2$ example I outlined clearly shows a flaw in my thought process since it seems to depend on the choice of basis used.

Comment: @beeclu Why does the fact that "the first entry of the derivative matrix is zero" imply that the function fails to satisfy the implicit function theorem? The only requirement of the implicit function theorem is that the derivative matrix *has non-zero determinant*

Comment: @beeclu Because you have not partitioned the input $M$ into two sets of variables (i.e. $x$ and $y$ as the other commenter notes), I suspect that you are thinking of the [inverse function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem) rather than the implicit function theorem. If not, you should clarify which variables are meant to be solved for as a function of the others

Comment: Ah, that would make sense. I had learned the IFT in my analysis course last year where we used Rudin’s book. The way the theorem is phrased in his book takes the first $n$ columns of the derivative matrix (the function was from $\mathbb{R}^{n+m} \to \mathbb{R}^n$, so the first $n$ columns form a square matrix) and Rudin requires this matrix to be invertible. But now your comment made me realize it was only phrased that way so we can say something like “we can rewrite $a$ in terms of $b,c,d$”. But if we generally want to just satisfy the IFT the non-zero determinant is sufficient.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Ah, I see. You’re right that I need to parition $M$ into an $x$ and a $y$ portion, but I’m unsure what to choose for the $x$ or $y$ portion. Is it irrelevant what choice is used?

Comment: @beeclu It might be possible to systematically discuss what should be done for arbitrary $x,y$ partitions of $M$, but the answer to the question of whether $M$ satisfies the hypotheses of the implicit function theorem depends on the specific choice of partition.

Comment: @beeclu From your last paragraph, it sounds like this question is based on an exercise from a textbook or from some homework assignment. If that is the case, it would be helpful if you could [edit] your question to include the exact phrasing of the original question.

Answer (score 1):

As I note in my comment, it is likely that you are really concerned with the [inverse function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem) rather than the implicit function theorem. With that, showing that your function "satisfies [the hypotheses of] the [inverse] function theorem" here means that the derivative of the function $f:M_k(\Bbb R) \to M_k(\Bbb R)$ at $I_k \in M_k(\Bbb R)$ given by $f(M) = M^TAM - A$ has an *invertible* derivative at $I_k$.

Another note: if $A = 0$, then $f(M) = 0$ clearly fails to be invertible, so I suppose $A \neq 0$ for convenience.

Because $f$ is a function over a matrix space, it is helpful to use a [coordinate invariant formulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative#Total_derivative,_total_differential_and_Jacobian_matrix) of the derivative. In particular, the derivative $\mathcal A = f'(I_k):M_k(\Bbb R)\to M_k(\Bbb R)$ is a linear map such for $H \in M_k(\Bbb R)$, we have
$$
f(I_k + H) = f(I_k) + \mathcal A(H) + o(\|H\|).
$$
To find this derivative, it suffices to write
$$
f(I_k + H) = (I_k + H)^TA(I_k + H) - A\\
= [I_k^T AI_k - A] + \underbrace {H^TA + AH}_{\mathcal A(H)} + H^TAH
\\ = f(I_k) + \mathcal A(H) + o(\|H\|).
$$
So, the derivative of $f$ at $I_k$ is $\mathcal A(H) = H^TA + AH$. We can see that this derivative will necessarily fail to be invertible by noting that plugging in the non-zero matrix $H = A$ yields
$$
\mathcal A(A) = (A)^TA + A(A) = -A^2 + A^2 = 0,
$$
so $\mathcal A$ fails to be injective.

If we want the matrix corresponding to this linear map relative to the ordering
$$
\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d} \leftrightarrow \pmatrix{a\\c\\b\\d},
$$
we can use the properties of [(column-major) vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) to find that
$$
\operatorname{vec}(\mathcal A(H)) = \operatorname{vec}(H^TA + A^TH) 
\\ = (A^T \otimes I)\operatorname{vec}(H^T) + (I \otimes A^T)\operatorname{vec}(H)
\\ = (A^T \otimes I)K^{(k,k)}\operatorname{vec}(H) + (I \otimes A^T)\operatorname{vec}(H)
\\ = [(A^T \otimes I)K^{(k,k)} + (I \otimes A^T)]\operatorname{vec}(H),
$$
where $\otimes$ denotes the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) and $K^{(k,k)}$ denotes a [commutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix). Correspondingly, we should find that the matrix of partial derivatives of $f$ (relative to this coordinate convention) will be $(A^T \otimes I)K^{(k,k)} + (I \otimes A^T)$. The fact that $\mathcal A$ fails to be invertible corresponds to the observation that $\det[(A^T \otimes I)K^{(k,k)} + (I \otimes A^T)] = 0$.

Whichever means are taken, we should eventually deduce that $f$ fails to satisfy the hypotheses of the inverse function theorem about $M = I_k$.